# powers, last 3 digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

For given $a\in\mathbb{N}$ define $x_1(a)=a$ and $x_{k+1}(a)=a^{x_k}$ for $k=1,2,\dots$. Find the last 3 digits of $\sum_{i=1}^{9}x_i(i)$.

the obvious attempt is to work modulo 1000, but maybe something more tricky would work faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Charmicael's Lambda:

$x_i\equiv x_{i+1}\bmod 4\implies x_{i+1}\equiv x_{i+2}\bmod 20 \implies$

$ x_{i+2}\equiv x_{i+3}\bmod 100\implies x_{i+3}\equiv x_{i+4}\bmod 1000$.

Notice if $a\equiv 1,3,4$ we have $a\equiv a^a$ and if $a\equiv 2$ we have $a^a\equiv a^{a^a}$.

Therefore $x_2\equiv x_3$ always. And so $x_5\equiv x_6\equiv x_7\equiv x_8\equiv x_9\bmod 1000$.

So we must only calculate $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5 \bmod 1000$ which should be possible using charmicael's lambda and exponentiation by squaring.